# Prevent input text element from accepting dropped element as input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to set up an `<input>` element so it does not accept any form of dropped input?

For instance, if we have the following elements on a page...

- `<img>`
- `<input type="text">`

...I would like to prevent the `<input>` element from **accepting** a dropped `<img>` as input.

I know it is possible to prevent dragging of the `<img>` element itself, but this is not something I want to do.

The solution I'm aiming for should work with any form of a dropped element (not restricted to images), and should preferably be in a vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, yes:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('false');
el.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Drop event blocked!")
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="accepts drops" type="text" id="true">

<input placeholder="doesnt accept" type="text" id="false">

<img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200">
```

Just catch the native `drop` event and cancel it on the input you wish to have disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Combine [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) with [`drop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop) event:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('drop', function(ev) {
  
  ev.preventDefault();

})
```

```html
<input type='text' value='ASD'>
<br>
<img src='http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg'>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier than you think, not complicated js required simply put this attribute on the input tag:

```
ondrop="return false;"
```