# Prevent input text element from accepting dropped text AND also not show the drop icon

Tags: html, google-chrome

Using this example, select `Hello` and drop it onto the input element.

```html
<input id="a" type="text" ondrop="return false">

<table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>

<script>
a.addEventListener("drop", e => e.preventDefault());
</script>
```

The drop is ignored by the `preventDefault()` however the icon still changes to suggest the text can be dropped here

[image]

rather than showing the no entry cursor indicating that the text can't be dropped.

[image]

Is there a way to make the input element show the can't be dropped here cursor?

I should probably add. This was tested on Windows 11, Chrome.

Note, this is not answered by: [Prevent input text element from accepting dropped element as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665928/prevent-input-text-element-from-accepting-dropped-element-as-input)

Which is about preventing the drop (which this is already doing) this question is about how to prevent the cursor from still showing the can drop cursor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent input text element from accepting dropped element as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665928/prevent-input-text-element-from-accepting-dropped-element-as-input)

Comment: @HereticMonkey That dupe still shows the [+] icon

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050102/how-can-i-hide-or-change-the-drag-not-allowed-cursor-during-a-dragging)

Comment: @mplungjan ill take a look at that one, see if it offers a solution.

Comment: the suggestion given is the right hint, but if I read the anwers correctly I see they are missing the real case in your question (but yet citing all the cases in the docs). You need specifically set `e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';`  after preventing the default behaviour inside the handler for the `dragover` event

Comment: @mplungjan unfortunately that doesn't help. That one is about preventing the not allowed cursor from showing, kind of the opposite of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @DiegoD that does it, thanks. Do you want to write that up as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment by @diego-d

> You need to set `e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';` after preventing
> the default behaviour inside the handler for the `dragover` event.

More specifically, using the example from the OP

```js
a.addEventListener("drop", e => e.preventDefault());
a.addEventListener("dragenter", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
});
a.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
});
```

The `dropEffect` `none` is needed for both `dragenter` as well as `dragover` otherwise the cursor briefly shows as the can drop cursor as you enter the input element.